# Rendering Html takes unnecessary space in table -RDLC Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am rendering Html in a column of a table in RDLC report. Here is the Html

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<DIV STYLE=\"text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;\">
<DIV>
<DIV><P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-weight:bold;\">Male: 20-80</SPAN></P>
<P><SPAN /></P><P STYLE=\"text-align:Center;text-indent:20;\"><SPAN /></P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The problem I am facing is that it takes unnecessary space as shown in the attached picture. The column is Normal range which is the last column in the table. I don't want the space below and above the rows.

Table:

[image]

I've made changes in `canGrow` and `canShrink` option but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing padding and html and body tags

```
<DIV STYLE=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:Left;font-family:Segoe UI;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12;color:#000000;\">
<DIV>
<DIV><P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-weight:bold;\">Male: 20-80</SPAN></P>
<P><SPAN /></P><P STYLE=\"text-align:Center;text-indent:20;\"><SPAN /></P>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

try also removing it from inner divs. Also draw borders in html objects to see who's pushing the borders